# Parsing pages python 2.7 using a Scrapy 1.2

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler, scrapy

Good day!

Questions on the implementation of a spider in python 2.7 to scrapy 1.2.

It is necessary that the spider from the page (https://vk.com/search?c%5Bage_from%5D=14&c%5Bage_to%5D=80&c%5Bcountry%5D=1&c%5Bmil_country%5D=1&c%5Bname%5D=1&c%5Bphoto%5D=1&c%5Bsection%5D=people&c%5Bsort%5D=1) without passing on the links pulled data (name, surname, age and city). How to pull data I know.
I do not understand how to call the function parse_item automatic passing in the response.

Enclosed developments spider that did:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, Identity
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector, Selector
from crawl.items import peoplesItem
import re
import scrapy


class cinemaLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_output_processor = Identity()

class cinemaSpider(CrawlSpider):

    # Имя паука
    name = "peoples"
    # Домены по которым можно ходить
    allowed_domains = ["vk.com"]
    # Адрес с которого начнется работа паука
    start_urls = ["https://vk.com/search?c%5Bage_from%5D=14&c%5Bage_to%5D=80&c%5Bcountry%5D=1&c%5Bmil_country%5D=1&c%5Bname%5D=1&c%5Bphoto%5D=1&c%5Bsection%5D=people&c%5Bsort%5D=1"]

    # xpath'и для выборки информации о людях
    # '//div[@id="results"]//div[@class="labeled name"]/a/text()' # Выборка фамилий и имени
    # '//div[@id="results"]/div[@class = "people_row search_row clear_fix"]//div[@class="labeled"]/text()' # Выборка города и возраста (если есть)

    # '//div[@id="results"]/div[@class = "people_row search_row clear_fix"]' # Получаем весь список людей

    def parse_item(self, response):
        """
        Данный метод занимается парсом страниц фильмов с помощью xpath-выражений
        :param response:
        :return:
        """
        print(u'Начинаем искать элементы на странице...') # Debug

        name = response.xpath(
            u'//div[@id="results"]//div[@class="labeled name"]/a/text()').extract()
        print (name)

        print(u'Элементы найдены. Начинаем записывать из в поля...')  # Debug

        Item = peoplesItem()

        # yield Item


    def isIntInString(self, string):
         """
         Данный метод проверяет, есть ли в переданной строке число. Если число есть, то он возвращает True.
         Если есть что-то кроме числа (не важно что) - False
         :param string: строка, в которой может быть число
         :return: boolean
         """
         resultre = re.findall(r'(\d+)', string, re.U | re.I | re.M)
         print(resultre)
         if len(resultre) != 0:
             return True
         return False
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The arguments given to `Rule` are not defined correctly. It needs `link_extractor` in which you can `allow` or `deny` URLs that you want to extract. Take a look at the example [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example)

Comment: @kiran.koduru Thank you, it's a little premera not an option - I have got confused in variants of the code and accidentally posted to the non-working rules. Now I am tinkering. Unfortunately it does not solve my problem, and it remains relevant. You can say something on the subject?